# Multiple class matching

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns

I'm working on a 2D geometric game in which I have a base abstract class `Figure` from which different implementations inherit (e.g. `CircleFigure`, `PolygonalFigure`). I need an abstract method in `Figure` that checks whether two of these figures are intersecting, let its signature be `public abstract boolean collision(Figure that)`.

The problem is that every pair of types of figures needs a different implementation of this method; i.e. for two circles I'd check that the sum of the two radii is less than the distance between the centers of the circles. But for a circle and a polygon, I'd use a completely different approach.

I'm aware of programming patterns and OOP concepts such as polymorphism which are appliable when we need to parametrize a method according to which subclass is executing it, but how can I parametrize according to which *pair* of classes call it?

Answer (score 1):

A common solution is:

```
abstract class Figure {
  public abstract boolean collision(Figure that);

  public abstract boolean collisionCircle(Circle that);
  // similar methods for other subclasses
}

class Circle extends Figure {
  public boolean collision(Figure that) {
    return that.collisionCircle(this);
  }

  public boolean collisionCircle(Circle that) { ... }
  // etc
}
```

The problem here is that 1) adding a subclass requires also adding a method to `Figure` and modifying other classes; 2) symmetry is not enforced.

More generally, search for "multiple dispatch" and "Visitor pattern" (e.g. https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/visitor/java/2).

Answer (score 0):

Given your requirements, I would suggest to move the actual logic into *another* "service" class, like:

```
public class CollisionDetector {
  public boolean areColliding(Figure first, Figure second)
```

That method would have to explicitly check the actual type of both arguments; do downcasts (I know, ugly) and then call corresponding methods like

```
 private boolean areCirclesColliding(Circle c1, Circle c2)
```

The point is: there is no clean way to keep that detection **inside** your different subclasses. As in: should the detection for circle --- polygon into CircleFigure; or into PolygonalFigure?!

I think this is one of the situations where your have to "cut out" your "cross cutting" logic and centralize it into a single "service provider".